# STL vector's implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am wondering how is STL `std::vector` implemented.

To be exact, does STL vector hold a table of objects in it or a table of pointers to objects?

In practical implementation: is it better to have `std::vector<char>` that's size is about `10^8`, or have an array of `char`?

The first option has obvious pros: iterating as in every other container, known size, automatic memory management, hard to do something really wrong.

The second option may use nine times less space (pointer is 64 bits where `char` is 8 bits) , but at at a cost of all those comfortable methods listed above.

I looked into 
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h
and saw that `push_back()` is implemented as below, but even examining alloc_traits.h gives me no clue how is it really done.

Type `char` was used only to show that the pointer's size is significant compared to the held value size.

I am using C++11.

```
void
push_back(const value_type& __x)
{
     if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
     {
         _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                                  __x);
         ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
     }
     else
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
     _M_emplace_back_aux(__x);
#else
     _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
#endif
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't hold pointers to the elements. A `vector<char>` with 10^8 elements will have a negligible bookkeeping footprint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A vector manages a single, contiguous array of objects, so it doesn't need a pointer to every element. It only needs:

- A pointer to the start of the array
- A pointer (or index) marking the end of the used elements (i.e. the size)
- A pointer (or index) marking the end of the allocated storage (i.e. the capacity)

(It also needs to store an allocator; but typically, that's stateless, and a decent implementation will use the "empty base class optimisation" to make sure it takes up no space in that case).

If you manage your own dynamic array, you will need at least two of these; so the extra cost of using a vector is a single pointer.

If you don't need dynamic allocation, then an automatic array (or `std::array`, if you want something more STLy) will be more efficient: it won't involve any heap allocations, or any extra storage. However, that's only possible if the size is known at compile-time, and there is a danger that a large array might overflow the stack.

Answer (score 3):

std::vector holds a continuous storage block, dynamically (re-)allocated.
Think of it as if it was:

```
struct vector { size_t size, capacity; void *data; };
```

Comment: It does not really hold `size` but a pointer to the end of storage.

Comment: @tobias: how it represents the size depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<T>` holds a sequence of objects of type `T` in a guaranteed contiguous buffer.

Regarding the question

> In practical implementation: is it better to have std::vector that's size is about 10^8, or have an array of char?

the size is irrelevant in itself.

However, if you allocate a large array of `char` as a local automatic variable, then likely you will run out of stack space, with very Undefined Behavior. You can avoid that by dynamically allocating the array. And one reasonable way to do that is to use a `std::string` (or a `std::vector`, but most likely this is a string).